# Can I see Folder Permissions on Windows in a Tree View?

Tags: windows, security, file-permissions, utilities

Is there a way to see folder/file permissions in a collapsable tree view in Windows?

What I think I need is something like:

```
+ folder1 - EntAdmins[RWX],JoeBloggs[R--],Administrators[RWX]]
+ folder2 - EntAdmins[RWX],JoeBloggs[RWX],JoesWife[R--]Administrators[RWX]]
```

And so on for lots of folders.

Ideally the tool would do something like below; when the "+" is clicked:

```
- folder1
|---+ Subfolder1 - EntAdmins[RWX],JoeBloggs[R--],Administrators[RWX]]
|---+ Subfolder2 - EntAdmins[RWX],JoeBloggs[R--],Administrators[RWX]]
|
+ folder2 - EntAdmins[RWX],JoeBloggs[RWX],JoesWife[R--]Administrators[RWX]]
```

Does something like this exist for Windows? I need to scan hundreds of folders for their permissions and would prefer not to do the right click and "Properties | Security | Advanced" just to see the permissions.

Comment: [How do I get only directories using Get-ChildItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085295/how-do-i-get-only-directories-using-get-childitem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx) from [Microsoft Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) does most of what you requested.  It does not however have the facility to *drill down*, but it's a very useful tool nonetheless.

Give it a try!

[image: AccessEnum Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/bb897332.accessenum(en-us,MSDN.10).gif))</sub>

Comment: Pretty much perfect for my needs! Here's a euro: €1! It doesn't have the drill-down, but it is better because it shows sub-folders/files that have different permissions from the parent.

Comment: I would say enjoy, but I know what a total headache sorting out ACLs on shares can be!

Answer (score 3):

My tool [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/) does exactly what you want. It has a tree view on the left and displays owner and permissions in the main area on the right:

[image]

As you can see, it even works with different object types: file system, registry, printers, services, shares, and WMI objects. You can change permissions, too, of course. And it has undo.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something though, this only works for local things, not for network drives.

Comment: @RickyMorse SetACL Studio works with remote machines, too. Just click the add computer icon in the upper left corner.

Comment: Hm. I've tried that, but it can't get the data from the share. I don't have access to the server, I just have access to a subfolder of a shared folder, and that's what I want to get permissions on.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do something similar to what you're talking about in Windows **Powershell** using the following command line:

```
dir -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq "TRUE" } | get-acl
```

Optionally, you could **pipe the output** to a file like this:

```
dir -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq "TRUE" } | get-acl | out-file "C:\report.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will bear this in mind, but the AccessEnum is the tool for me at the moment.

Comment: I understand.  It sounded like a good tool but I had just this morning received my PowerShell tip of the day containing a similar bit of code and thought I'd share that as an alternate means of achieving the same goal.  Use what works, definitely!

Comment: Can I alter this to skip a folder that I don't have access to? for example, when I ran this (not as admin) I got an error ("unauthorized operation") and the report stopped at the folder I did not have access to